# How to disable ANSI escape code output during a Rollup build?

Tags: vite, rollupjs

When doing a runtime build with vite it uses rollupjs to do the code transformation, which prints some interesting information in the terminal. While this is fine on a local dev box, it becomes a nuisance in a CI build (here Jenkins):

```
[36mvite v4.0.3 [32mbuilding for production...[36m[39m
transforming...

Missing export "createServer" has been shimmed in module "__vite-browser-external".

Missing export "Socket" has been shimmed in module "__vite-browser-external".
[32m✓[39m 3098 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...
computing gzip size...
[2mbuild/[22m[2massets/[22m[32meditor-side-line-straight-3b1dfbb4.svg            [39m[1m[2m    0.41 kB[22m[1m[22m
[2mbuild/[22m[2massets/[22m[32msquiggle-cb9fe55e.svg                             [39m[1m[2m    0.47 kB[22m[1m[22m
[2mbuild/[22m[2massets/[22m[32mmarkdown-8b37fca1.svg                             [39m[1m[2m    0.58 kB[22m[1m[22m
[2mbuild/[22m[2massets/[22m[32mshell-40c17629.svg                                [39m[1m[2m    0.60 kB[22m[1m[22m
[2mbuild/[22m[2massets/[22m[32mremove-899a6ae3.svg                               [39m[1m[2m    0.65 kB[22m[1m[22m
```

Is it possible to disable the ANSI escape code in the output to get just the text? Ideally, this should be configurable (say, using an env variable, to know when doing a CI build).

Answer (score 1):

Set an environment variable `NO_COLOR=1`.

Vite uses [picocolors](https://github.com/alexeyraspopov/picocolors) which is [`NO_COLOR`](https://no-color.org/) friendly; the `NO_COLOR` standard states that setting this environment variable to any non-empty string will disabled the colors in supporting applications.

Comment: A possible solution, thanks, though a pretty radical one. Setting the NO_COLOR env var disables colors for all apps and libraries which support that, which is not always what people want.